# Ruby return matching character size

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to make a game which involves it returning the amount of characters that you've guessed that are in the correct position of the randomly generated word (eg., word is "board", and you enter "boat", you'd get 2/5, and you entered "board", you'd get 5/5).

```
word = File.readlines("wordslist.txt").sample;
guess = gets
same = guess.each_char.zip(word.each_char).select{ |g,w| g == w }.size
```

It works fine for any guess under the word length. If the word was "bye" and I entered "byk" it would return 3/3, but if I entered "by" it would return 2/3. Just looking to see if I'm doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because both `File.readlines` and `gets` do not trim the trailing newline character from the returned string.

```
irb(main):001:0> File.read("wordslist.txt")
=> "hello\nbye\n"
irb(main):002:0> File.readlines("wordslist.txt")
=> ["hello\n", "bye\n"]
irb(main):003:0> gets
bye
=> "bye\n"
```

When your dictionary contains "bye\n" and you type "byk\n", there are actually 3 matches, "b", "y", and "\n". If you enter "by\n" though, the newline character doesn't match. The newline character will only match if the input strings are of the same length, and the returned value would be 1 more than you'd expect.

To fix this, you can call `.chomp` on both the strings to remove the trailing whitespace before comparing the characters:

```
word = File.readlines("wordslist.txt").sample.chomp;
guess = gets.chomp
same = guess.each_char.zip(word.each_char).select{ |g,w| g == w }.size
```

---

Tip: You can use `.count` instead of `.select` and `.size`:

```
same = guess.each_char.zip(word.each_char).count{ |g,w| g == w }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_same_position(guess, word)
  (0..word.size-1).count { |i| guess[i] == word[i] }
end

number_same_position("boat", "board")   #=> 3
number_same_position("bait", "board")   #=> 1
number_same_position("sulk", "board")   #=> 0
number_same_position("boater", "board") #=> 3
number_same_position("", "board")       #=> 0
```

One could instead use three dots (`(0...word.size)`) but I always use two dots. Recall `string[i] #=> nil` when `i >= string.size`.